Aleph sequence fixed points and the least inaccessible
Using the properties of the least inaccessible cardinal (being a regular fixed point of the aleph function) I was able to prove that the least inaccessible $\kappa$ is the $\kappa$-th fixed point of the aleph function which is monotonous and continuous at limit ordinals.
Is the converse true?
Is the first cardinal with this property inaccessible?

If $\alpha$ is worldly (i.e., if $V_\alpha$ models $\mathsf{ZFC}$ then it is an $\alpha$th fixed point of aleph function but the least worldly cardinal has cofinality $\omega$.

@Hanul: Even more can be said. The fixed points form a club, so ZF already proves the existence of fixed-fixed points, etc.

@Asaf Thank you for your clarification. I  vaguely noticed it after typing my comment, but I was too sleepy to comment it...
